# Why doesn't this ANTLR grammar derive the string `baba`?

Tags: antlr, context-free-grammar

---

Using ANTLR v4.9.3, I created the following grammar …

```
grammar G ;
start : s EOF ;
s : 'ba' a b ;
a : 'b' ;
b : 'a' ;
```

---

Given the above grammar, I thought that the following derivation is possible …

> `start` → `s` → `'ba' a b` → `'ba' 'b' b` → `'ba' 'b' 'a'` = `'baba'`

However, my Java test program indicates a syntax error occurs when trying to parse the string `baba`.

Shouldn't the string `baba` be in the language generated by grammar `G` ?

---

Comment: It doesn't work because the tokens recognized are { 'ba' 'ba' EOF }. Neither a nor b cannot derive 'ba'. The lexer is not parser context sensitive (usually). When developing your grammar, it's a good idea to print the tokens out when you see something unusual.

Comment: It appears that the fix is to change the rule `s : 'ba' a b ;` to `s : 'b' 'a' a b ;` so that the string `ba` is not considered to be a token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the conclusion/answer is already in the comments, here an answers that explains it in a bit more detail.

When defining literal tokens inside parser rule (the `'ba'`, `'a'` and `'b'`), ANTLR implicitly creates the following grammar:

```
grammar G ;
start : s EOF ;
s : T__0 a b ;
a : T__1 ;
b : T__2 ;

T__0 : 'ba';
T__1 : 'b';
T__2 : 'a';
```

Now, when the lexer get the input `"baba"`, it will create 2 `T__0` tokens. The lexer is not driven by whatever the parser is trying to match. It works independently from the parser. The lexer creates tokens following these 2 rules:

1. try to match as many characters as possible for a rule
2. when 2 (or more) lexer rules match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

Because of rule 1, it is apparent that 2 `T__0` tokens are created.

As you already mentioned in a comment, removing the `'ba'` token (and using `'b'` followed by `'a'`) would resolve the issue:

```
grammar G ;
start : s EOF ;
s : 'b' 'a' a b ;
a : 'b' ;
b : 'a' ;
```

which would really be the grammar:

```
grammar G ;
start : s EOF ;
s : T__0 T__1 a b ;
a : T__0 ;
b : T__1 ;

T__0 : 'b';
T__1 : 'a';
```